# What happens when you procession an encampment without having a gold/plunder in your hand?

Tags: dominion, dominion-dark-ages, dominion-empires

What happens when you play [Procession](http://wiki.dominionstrategy.com/index.php/Procession)
on a [Encampment](http://wiki.dominionstrategy.com/index.php/Encampment) with out having a gold or plunder in your hand?

Does procession lose track of Encampment therefore it not able to trash it and it ends up back in the supple?  Do you still gain a card and if so what value of card you gain?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Procession plays Encampment for the first time. You don't reveal a Plunder or Gold, so you set Encampment aside. This does not prevent Procession from playing it a second time, but both Encampment's attempt to set itself aside again, and Procession's attempt to trash it, will fail because it's not currently in play. You gain an Action card costing $3 ($1 more than Encampment), then at the end of your turn you return Encampment to its pile.

Reasons for what happens:

1. Procession needs to wait for Encampment to finish being played twice before it can do the trashing. It can't find Encampment if it's set aside (because it has "lost track"), so it can't trash it.
2. Procession's "gain an Action card" effect does *not* depend on successfully trashing the played card (as noted in the FAQ).
3. "Lose track" effects only happen when an effect tries to move a card, but the card is in an unexpected location. So Procession "thinks" the Encampment is in play and tries to move it to the trash, but since it's not in the "in-play area" it can't trash it. But being set aside doesn't change Encampment's text or cost so it still does the same thing when it gets played again, and it can still be used to calculate the cost of the card gained by Possession.

Comment: And 3) “lose track” only prevents a card from being moved; it doesn’t prevent it from being played or from getting information such as the cost. (These seem to be common misconceptions about the lose track rule).

Comment: Yes, that. I had it in mind, but didn't explicitly state it. I will add it to my answer.

Comment: I assume you don't get to keep the Encampment if you draw a gold off the second time it is played since it has already been put to the side and has been lost track of?

Comment: That's right - once it's set aside, it will definitely be going back to the supply even if it's played again and you draw a Gold.